# Add trend line to bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add 2 trend lines to the barplot that I currently have.

This is the dataset that I have

```
structure(list(yr = c("2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", 
"2011", "2011", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
"2012"), weekday = structure(c(5L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 
1L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"), class = "factor"), 
    cnt = c(181975L, 181469L, 171142L, 169104L, 183436L, 188807L, 
    166547L, 295964L, 306332L, 291879L, 288597L, 290031L, 301096L, 
    275677L)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), groups = structure(list(
    yr = c("2011", "2012"), .rows = structure(list(1:7, 8:14), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

As seen from the graph, the barplots are separated into 2011 and 2012. I would want to show 2 trend lines (2011 and 2012) on this graph to show the trend across the weekdays for both years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by trendline you mean just a line that shows the same data as the bars but is connected...

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- structure(list(yr = c("2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", 
                              "2011", "2011", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
                              "2012"), weekday = structure(c(5L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 
                                                             1L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
                                                                                                 "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"), class = "factor"), 
                       cnt = c(181975L, 181469L, 171142L, 169104L, 183436L, 188807L, 
                               166547L, 295964L, 306332L, 291879L, 288597L, 290031L, 301096L, 
                               275677L)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), groups = structure(list(
                                 yr = c("2011", "2012"), .rows = structure(list(1:7, 8:14), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
                                                                                                                          "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                              "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = weekday, y = cnt, group = yr)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = yr), position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = yr), position = position_dodge(width = 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: hi thanks for the reply! yes this is what i want. but how do i change the color of the lines? i tried adding aes(fill = yr) to geom_line but it does not change the color.

Comment: Just updated answer with that. For `geom_col` you need to modify the `fill` aesthetic, but for points and lines it's the `color`.